# The serialized data is invalid

Tags: asp.net

I am facing some problems when i deploy my site in to a load balance server. The stack trace is given below. Any help would be appreciated

> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'App_Web_ujlndqyx,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String
>   name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName) +0
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String
>   name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +54
>   System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark) +39
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName,
>   Boolean throwOnError) +60
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.DeserializeType(SerializerBinaryReader
>   reader) +201
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.DeserializeValue(SerializerBinaryReader
>   reader) +955
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.DeserializeValue(SerializerBinaryReader
>   reader) +395
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.DeserializeValue(SerializerBinaryReader
>   reader) +205
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.DeserializeValue(SerializerBinaryReader
>   reader) +218
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.DeserializeValue(SerializerBinaryReader
>   reader) +205
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   inputStream) +163
>
> [ArgumentException: The serialized
>   data is invalid.]
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   inputStream) +228
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String
>   inputString) +303
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String
>   serializedState) +5
>   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter
>   formatter, String serializedState) +37
>   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
>   +116
>
> [ViewStateException: Invalid
>   viewstate.    Client IP: 114.130.35.83
>     Port: 2161  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
>     ViewState:
>   /wEPDwUJMzI0MDgwMzY4DxYCHgtDdXJyZW50VmlldwspbE9yZGVySm91cm5leURlZmF1bHQrQ3VycmVudFZpZXdFbnVtLCBBcHBfV2ViX3VqbG5kcXl4LCBWZXJzaW9uPTAuMC4wLjAsIEN1bHR1cmU9bmV1dHJhbCwgUHVibGljS2V5VG9rZW49bnVsbAIWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYGAgMPFgIeCWlubmVyaHRtbAXSBDx1bD4KPGxpPjxhIGNsYXNzPSJzZWxlY3RlZCIgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly9idXNpbmVzcy5idC5jb20vIj5CdXNpbmVzcyBob21lPC9hPjwvbGk+CjxsaSBjbGFzcz0iaGFzX2Ryb3BfZG93biBzZWxlY3RlZCI+IDxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHBzOi8vYnVzaW5lc3MuYnQuY29tL3Byb2R1Y3RzLWFuZC1zZXJ2aWNlcy8iPlByb2R1Y3RzICZhbXA7IHNlcnZpY2VzPC9hPiA8YSBjbGFzcz0iZHJvcF9kb3duIiBocmVmPSIjZm9vdGVyIj5WaWV3IHByb2R1Y3RzIGFuZCBzZXJ2aWNlcyAocG9wLXVwKTwvYT4gPC9saT4KPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHBzOi8vYnVzaW5lc3MuYnQuY29tL3BhY2thZ2VzLyI+UGFja2FnZXM8L2E+PC9saT4KPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuaW5zaWdodC5idC5jb20vIj5CdXNpbmVzcyBpbnNpZ2h0PC9hPjwvbGk+CjxsaT48YSBocmVmPSJodHRwczovL3d3dy5idC5jb20vY21wL3B1YmxpYy9odWIuZG8iPllvdXIgYWNjb3VudD...]
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The state
>   information is invalid for this page
>   and might be corrupted.]
>   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception
>   inner, String persistedState, String
>   errorPageMessage, Boolean
>   macValidationError) +118
>   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowViewStateError(Exception
>   inner, String persistedState) +13
>   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
>   +222    System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
>   +107    System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +43 
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6230
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +247
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>   +79    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context) +23
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) +111
>   ASP.toj_application_orderjourney_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) in
>   c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\82a64fa9\62e4fa0\App_Web_fewmyzsj.0.cs:0
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +406    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +76

Comment: Are you using the same machine key settings on all machines? http://www.shnake.com/blog/?p=604

Comment: Yes. went through that path already : <br/>   <machineKey validationKey="9846372AB6543DEF87639ABCDEF875643298DEC34562964E" decryptionKey="9846352AB6543DEF87639A1CDEF875633298DEC34562964E" validation="3DES"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never" >

Comment: The only other issue I could suggest is that you're running against a different framework version, is it a .NET 2.0 application?

Answer (score 2):

Move the class you put in viewstate in a separate assembly, not in the web project assembly.
If you don't, on the fly compilation of aspx code will produce temp names, different for all web servers

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but managed to cure it now.  We are running a web farm with 2 servers.  Machine keys match.  I think my problem is related to using Oracle's session state software.  When I put any object, a simple list, in the viewstate things go awry.  I get this error as soon as it serves a post back on the other server than the original get was served.

Two interesting items I noticed:

1. the name of the file it cannot find when serving request on server
   A, does not exist on server A, however it is the name of the file on
   server B.  The difference in the file names is the hash it adds at
   the end,

   > App_Web_form_create_excel_data_template.aspx.cdcab7d2.wpiiisfb

   on server A and

   > App_Web_form_create_excel_data_template.aspx.cdcab7d2.lkw6qbsg.dll

   on server B.  The .compile files on each respective server points to the correct file.
2. the session state oracle stores in the oracle database becomes
   corrupt and unusable.  Its lock column gets a 1 in it that never
   clears.  I must either delete the row or delete the asp.net session
   cookie from the browser.

I then found the solution thanks to the Microsoft KB article [Troubleshooting the "View state is invalid" error with ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829743).

**I had declared a variable as an enum and saved it in viewstate.**  I am assuming enum is considered a dynamic class and so as the article states the name of the source file is used in the serialization of the viewstate item that was the enum!  Since the names of the source files are different on the 2 web servers that make up the farm when it serialized its value on one server and tried to deserialize its value on the other the error occurred!

Answer (score 0):

Your Inner Exception is about `ViewState` but about file not found exception:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_ujlndqyx, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
```

This means that your server tried to resolve some class type, and didn't find anything corresponding.
Try to check this:

1. I think that you've linked some library in your project, and have deployed it on one machine, but not to your server.
2. Maybe some dll from GAC is missing
3. Maybe IIS settings for the .NET version is different from your local machine or you simply running the application on the machine with different .NET version